# Bundler could not find compatible versions for gem xx

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I'm upgrading rails from 4.2 to 5.0, and I'm getting some mean dependency issues.
When I run `bundle update` i get the following output.
The thing is that when i look through the messages, it looks like the gems should be able to install just fine when looking at the version requirements.

I also tried to delete my Gemfile.lock, that didn't help.

Any suggestions would be appreciated.

```
Bundler could not find compatible versions for gem "actionpack":
  In Gemfile:
    activeadmin (~> 1.1.0) was resolved to 1.1.0, which depends on
      inherited_resources (~> 1.7) was resolved to 1.10.0, which depends on
        actionpack (< 6.0, >= 5.0)

    rails (= 5.0.0) was resolved to 5.0.0, which depends on
      actionpack (= 5.0.0)

    ransack (= 1.8.10) was resolved to 1.8.10, which depends on
      actionpack (< 5.2, >= 3.0)

    route_translator (= 5.0.0) was resolved to 5.0.0, which depends on
      actionpack (< 5.1, >= 5.0.0)

    simple_form (= 3.5.0) was resolved to 3.5.0, which depends on
      actionpack (< 5.2, > 4)

    slim-rails (~> 3.2.0) was resolved to 3.2.0, which depends on
      actionpack (>= 3.1)

Bundler could not find compatible versions for gem "activeadmin":
  In Gemfile:
    activeadmin (~> 1.1.0)

    activeadmin_quill_editor (= 0.2.0) was resolved to 0.2.0, which depends on
      activeadmin (>= 1.0)

Bundler could not find compatible versions for gem "activemodel":
  In Gemfile:
    openid_connect (~> 1.2.0) was resolved to 1.2.0, which depends on
      activemodel

    paperclip (= 5.2.1) was resolved to 5.2.1, which depends on
      activemodel (>= 4.2.0)

    rails (= 5.0.0) was resolved to 5.0.0, which depends on
      activemodel (= 5.0.0)

    simple_form (= 3.5.0) was resolved to 3.5.0, which depends on
      activemodel (< 5.2, > 4)

Bundler could not find compatible versions for gem "activerecord":
  In Gemfile:
    friendly_id (= 5.0.5) was resolved to 5.0.5, which depends on
      activerecord (>= 4.0.0)

    rails (= 5.0.0) was resolved to 5.0.0, which depends on
      activerecord (= 5.0.0)

    ransack (= 1.8.10) was resolved to 1.8.10, which depends on
      activerecord (< 5.2, >= 3.0)

Bundler could not find compatible versions for gem "activesupport":
  In Gemfile:
    paperclip (= 5.2.1) was resolved to 5.2.1, which depends on
      activesupport (>= 4.2.0)

    rails (= 5.0.0) was resolved to 5.0.0, which depends on
      activesupport (= 5.0.0)

    ransack (= 1.8.10) was resolved to 1.8.10, which depends on
      activesupport (< 5.2, >= 3.0)

    route_translator (= 5.0.0) was resolved to 5.0.0, which depends on
      activesupport (< 5.1, >= 5.0.0)

Bundler could not find compatible versions for gem "autoprefixer-rails":
  In Gemfile:
    autoprefixer-rails (~> 9.7.4)

    bootstrap (~> 4.4.1) was resolved to 4.4.1, which depends on
      autoprefixer-rails (>= 9.1.0)

Bundler could not find compatible versions for gem "devise":
  In Gemfile:
    devise (= 4.0.0)

    devise-token_authenticatable (~> 0.5.3) was resolved to 0.5.3, which depends on
      devise (< 4.4.0, >= 4.0.0)

Bundler could not find compatible versions for gem "execjs":
  In Gemfile:
    execjs (= 1.4.0)

    autoprefixer-rails (~> 9.7.4) was resolved to 9.7.6, which depends on
      execjs

    uglifier (~> 3.0) was resolved to 3.2.0, which depends on
      execjs (< 3, >= 0.3.0)

Bundler could not find compatible versions for gem "inherited_resources":
  In Gemfile:
    inherited_resources

    activeadmin (~> 1.1.0) was resolved to 1.1.0, which depends on
      inherited_resources (~> 1.7)

Bundler could not find compatible versions for gem "jquery-rails":
  In Gemfile:
    jquery-rails (= 4.0.0)

    activeadmin (~> 1.1.0) was resolved to 1.1.0, which depends on
      jquery-rails

Bundler could not find compatible versions for gem "mimemagic":
  In Gemfile:
    mimemagic

    paperclip (= 5.2.1) was resolved to 5.2.1, which depends on
      mimemagic (~> 0.3.0)

Bundler could not find compatible versions for gem "nokogiri":
  In Gemfile:
    nokogiri (= 1.8.2)

    paperclip (= 5.2.1) was resolved to 5.2.1, which depends on
      mimemagic (~> 0.3.0) was resolved to 0.3.10, which depends on
        nokogiri (~> 1)

    savon (~> 2.12.1) was resolved to 2.12.1, which depends on
      nokogiri (>= 1.8.1)

Bundler could not find compatible versions for gem "paperclip":
  In Gemfile:
    paperclip (= 5.2.1)

    paperclip-compression (~> 1.1) was resolved to 1.1.1, which depends on
      paperclip (>= 5.2.1)

Bundler could not find compatible versions for gem "railties":
  In Gemfile:
    coffee-rails (= 5.0.0) was resolved to 5.0.0, which depends on
      railties (>= 5.2.0)

    rails (= 5.0.0) was resolved to 5.0.0, which depends on
      railties (= 5.0.0)

Bundler could not find compatible versions for gem "rake":
  In Gemfile:
    rake (= 10.4.2)

    paperclip (= 5.2.1) was resolved to 5.2.1, which depends on
      mimemagic (~> 0.3.0) was resolved to 0.3.10, which depends on
        rake

    rails (= 5.0.0) was resolved to 5.0.0, which depends on
      railties (= 5.0.0) was resolved to 5.0.0, which depends on
        rake (>= 0.8.7)

Bundler could not find compatible versions for gem "responders":
  In Gemfile:
    responders (~> 2.3.0)

    devise (= 4.0.0) was resolved to 4.0.0, which depends on
      responders

    activeadmin (~> 1.1.0) was resolved to 1.1.0, which depends on
      inherited_resources (~> 1.7) was resolved to 1.10.0, which depends on
        responders (~> 2.0)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Most likely you have some strong constraints on some particular gems in your Gemfile that's it's blocking bundle from updating a dependency.

Comment: Thank you Federico!
What I did exactly was to comment almost all gems in the gemfile until I could run `bundle update rails`. Then i uncommented the gems one by one. When I had problems with specific gems, i increased the versions until it worked.
My main takeaway is that the messages by bundle aren't that helpful

Comment: @sorenwiz I'm happy you managed to resolved that, and yes bundler messages are not always very useful haha.